# Cannot read property 'then' of undefined when installing ember-cli-coffeescript

Tags: ember-cli, ember-cli-addons

Upon installing `ember-cli` i wanted to install the `coffeescript` add on using:

```
ember install ember-cli-coffeescript
```

as shown in the documentation but I get the error:

```
WARNING: Skipping npm install: package.json not found
package.json not found
Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
   at Class.run (/home/daniel/.nvm/versions/node/v7.6.0/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/tasks/addon-install.js:43:7)
at Class.run (/home/daniel/.nvm/versions/node/v7.6.0/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/commands/install.js:39:25)
at Class.<anonymous> (/home/daniel/.nvm/versions/node/v7.6.0/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/command.js:241:20)
at initializePromise (/home/daniel/.nvm/versions/node/v7.6.0/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:588:5)
at PromiseExt.Promise (/home/daniel/.nvm/versions/node/v7.6.0/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1076:31)
at new PromiseExt (/home/daniel/.nvm/versions/node/v7.6.0/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/ext/promise.js:32:8)
at Class.validateAndRun (/home/daniel/.nvm/versions/node/v7.6.0/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/command.js:195:12)
at /home/daniel/.nvm/versions/node/v7.6.0/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/cli/cli.js:130:22
at tryCatch (/home/daniel/.nvm/versions/node/v7.6.0/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:538:12)
at invokeCallback (/home/daniel/.nvm/versions/node/v7.6.0/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:553:13)
```

I don't understand what this means. I have seen this question asked in different contexts for Angular.js but those questions are related to peoples code. This question is related to the installation itself. this is a brandnew project and install.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `package.json` file usually in the project root, called package.json - this file holds various metadata relevant to the project. This file is used to give information to npm that allows it to identify the project as well as handle the project's dependencies.

Make sure you have a proper inited Ember project. If you do not have a `package.json` file. Try to re-init your project using `Ember init` inside your project folder.

**Attention**: the init process may overwrite the existing files in your project. Backup if it is important.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a package.json file? Easily done by running npm init

Comment: What is the package.json file for? Where should it go (is it project specific?), is it an ember thing or a node/npm thing?

Comment: It's used by npm to manage dependencies (amongst other things). For instance the package you're trying to install: 'ember-cli-coffeescript', will have different versions. And instead of finding the version you need by browsing, then downloading etc.. You can just specify the version in your ```package.json``` file and anyone that then uses your code will automatically get the dependencies when they execute ```npm install```. Also Ember addons read the package.json file on install, unless I'm mistaken.